# Filter text with a QRegExp

Tags: regex, qt

I want to filter out `${...}` with a `QRegExp`, such that it retuns a `QStringList` of all selected elements:

> "${NAME}" << "${DAY}" << "${MEH}" << "${MEH}" << "${MEH}"

but somehow it doesn't work:

```
QString text = "Hello ${NAME} \
        How is your ${DAY} so? \
        Bye, ${MEH} ${MEH}\
        ${MEH}";

// Regex: /(\${.*})/g
QRegExp rx("/(\\${.*})/g");
QStringList list;
int pos = 0;

while ((pos = rx.indexIn(text, pos)) != -1) {
    QString val = rx.cap(1);
    list << val;
    qDebug () << "Val: " << val;
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
```

No output at all? What I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

`QRegularExpression` works, but only on a per-line and not per-entry level. Ideas?

```
QString text = "Hello ${NAME} \
        How is your ${DAY} so? \
        Bye, ${MEH} ${MEH}\
        ${MEH}";

QRegularExpression rx("(\\${.*})");
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = rx.globalMatch(text);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    qDebug() << "Value: " << match.captured(0);
}
```

Output:

> Value:  "${NAME} \t\t\tHow is your ${DAY} so? \t\t\tBye, ${MEH} ${MEH}\t\t\t${MEH}"

Comment: QRegExp rx("/(\\\\${.*})/g"); doesn't work

Comment: oops yeah you're right that's to match a backslash.

Comment: you may try `QRegularExpression` if you're using Qt5. It's perl-compliant, while `QRegExp` is not. I'm also not sure /.../g is going to do what you think in Qt. `QRegularExpression` includes a `globalMatch` function though.

Comment: Thank you, but please take a look at my updated answer

Comment: can you add your desired output string to the question? Is is `"NAME \t\t\tHow is your DAY so? \t\t\tBye, MEH MEH\t\t\tMEH"`?

Comment: A QStringList of all selected elements: "${NAME}" << "${DAY}" << "${MEH}" << "${MEH}" << "${MEH}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the regex to `QRegularExpression rx("(\\${.*?})");`

Your first attempt didn't work because `QRegExp` doesn't support global matching via `/.../g`, and in general, is not perl-compliant. In Qt5, you're better off using the much-improved `QRegularExpression`.

Your second attempt didn't work because your regex is too greedy. It's grabbing the opening curly brace `{` up to the *last* closing curly brace `}`.

If you add a question mark to the `.*` capture, you will turn off the greediness, and in this case it will only capture what you are looking for.

Be careful trying to scale this solution much farther though. In general, [*Regular expressions are not parsers*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la).